# Physical limits or empirical data on ratios of bulk modulus, shear modulus and density

Tags: elasticity, continuum-mechanics

The elastic dynamics of an isotropic continuum (solid or fluid) can be described in terms of the bulk modulus ($\kappa$), shear modulus ($\mu$, zero in a fluid) and density. (The two elastic moduli are sometimes expressed in terms of other variables such as Young's modulus [$E$], Lamé's first parameter [$\lambda$], or Poisson's ratio [$\nu$]. Any two of these parameters is sufficient to determine the others, as shown in this Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_modulus.)

What ranges can these parameters take, relative to one another? I already know that all three should be positive, and $\kappa$ is always greater than $\mu$ (see this question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/170129/135804). Any additional constraints would be helpful. Although empirical data will not give theoretical answers, please provide any links to any compilations of the elastic parameters of various materials.

Comment: I don't see how your question is not answered in the previous question. For the elastic potential energy to be positive definite $\kappa$ and $\mu$ should be positive, this translates into $\nu \in [-1, 1/2]$ for the Poisson ratio.

Comment: You can find a compilation of materials done by me here: https://figshare.com/articles/Materials_database/9941750